# Merge several different csv in a single dataset

Tags: r, merge

How do I merge 100 csv files in a single data set? Rows and column number are different.

Each csv file has different columns and rows.
I tried many ways to merge but I fail as below.
Could you give me any advice?

1st try:

```
files=list.files(pattern=".csv$")
files
mydata1=lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

mydata2 <- function(x) {

x.diff <- setdiff(colnames(x), colnames(y))
y.diff <- setdiff(colnames(y), colnames(x))

x[, c(as.character(y.diff))] <- NA

y[, c(as.character(x.diff))] <- NA

return(mydata2)
}

merdata= merge(lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), files, by=c("location","yearmon", "MME"), all=T)
```

> # Error in data.frame(list(yearmon = c("1983-01", "1983-02", "1983-03",  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 278, 398

#

I have 1253 csv files. I want to make these files to one data set.
Same column name of each files should be the same name, not 'x.column' like this.I attached sample result file. You can easy to understand what I want to do. I show you 2 example files as bellow.  "dput(mydata1[1:2])" coding data as bellow. The final goal is merging 1253 files to one data set. 
Thank you so much for your help again.

```
 .Names = c("yearmon", "E01", "E02", "E03", "E04", "E05", 
"E06", "E07", "E08", "E09", "E10", "E11", "E12", "E13", "E14", 
"E15", "E16", "E17", "E18", "E19", "E20", "MME", "location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-398L)), 

 .Names = c("yearmon", "E01", 
"E02", "E03", "E04", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E08", "E09", "E10", 
"MME", "location"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -278L
)))
```

#

[**Sample Result**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0C2l6.jpg)
[iefile_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85GPw.jpg)  [iefile_2]

Comment: Keep all csv files as list - output of lapply part of your code, then use merge in a loop.

Comment: Maybe merging isn't what you really need. It will produce resulting `data.frame` with thousands of columns if ends successfully, which is not convenient for work at all. Besides, I doubt it will work here - your `data.frame`s have common columns (for example `E01` and `E02`) which contain different numbers (no common) and `merge`, which in fact does `INNER JOIN` will produce empty resulting table. I suggest you first reshape your tables in `mydata1` into 5-column view (look function `gather` from package `tidyr`) and then bind them together with `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. Actually, I just started to learn R in these day. I may need to study a lot. At this moment, I can not follow your advice due to my short understanding. Sorry about that. If you don't mind, could you try how to do? Let me give you data files. Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your question and add a piece of your data. Please enter in `R` command `dput(mydata[1:2])` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: I updated the information what you advised. Please see that.

Comment: I found codes as below. Thank you all~.                                                               file.list <- list.files(path = " ", pattern='.csv')
datafile_list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv)
MergedData <- rbindlist(datafile_list, idcol = "deletethis", fill=T)

Answer (score 1):

Since the datasets share the same columns, you could base your approach on row bind `rbind()`. `rbind()` is a function that combines vectors, matrices or data frames by rows. You should create a list of your datasets and feed the function with them.

```
rbind(dt1,dt2,.., dtn)

dt1.csv:

Lett    Color  Num
A       w      0.4
A       b      -0.6
B       b      1.2
C       w      -0.70

dt2.csv:

Lett    Color   Num
D       w       2.89
D       b       0.06
D       b       0.62
D       w       0.5
D       w       9.3
B       w       -2.3
A       b       -0.1
```

Read in the data from the file:

```
> dt1 <- read.csv("dt1.csv", header=T, sep=",")
> dt2 <- read.csv("dt2.csv", header=T, sep=",")

> dt_merged <- rbind(dt1, dt2)
> dt_merged

Lett    Color  Num
A       w      0.4
A       b      -0.6
B       b      1.2
C       w      -0.70
D       w      2.89
D       b      0.06
D       b      0.62
D       w      0.5
D       w      9.3
B       w      -2.3
A       b      -0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
install.packages(c("dplyr", "tidyr"), dependencies = T)
require("dplyr")
require("tidyr")

files <- list.files(pattern=".csv$")
mydata1 <- lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))

mydata2 <- lapply(mydata1, function(df) {
  df %>% gather(e_num, e_value, -yearmon, -MME, -location)
}) %>% bind_rows
```